# Django, python 2.7 : insert multiple records into two related tables

Tags: python, django

New to Django orm and i need guidance:

i want to insert 5 records in a table say 'Table1' with PK 'table1Primary'

then insert same number of records into another table 'Table2' with table 1 PK 'table1Primary' as foreign key

example:Table1 primary key

1. pk1
2. pk2
3. pk3
4. pk4

Table 2 foreign keys

1. pk1
2. pk2
3. pk3
4. pk4

[i would rather use bulk_create or any other optimized way rather than writing separate insert statements]

code that doesn't work, i am assuming because of this line
 eft_fulfillment_uid=ef , i end up with 5*5 inserts in second

```
 for i in range(5):
    ef = Fulfillment.objects.create(
        fullfillment_uid=generateid(),
        ...
        ...
    )
    ef.save()

for i in range(5):
    por = OutReq.objects.create(
        out_req_uid=random.randint(500, 1000000000),
        fulfillment_uid=ef,
        ...
        ...
    )
    por.save()
```

Comment: Why do you save the instances after creating them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a new `OutReq` object for every `Fulfillment` object, do it within the same loop. Otherwise you will only use the last value that `ef` was set to.

```
for i in range(5):
    ef = Fulfillment.objects.create(
        fullfillment_uid=generateid(),
        ...
        ...
    )
    por = OutReq.objects.create(
        out_req_uid=random.randint(500, 1000000000),
        fulfillment_uid=ef.fullfillment_uid,
        ...
        ...
    )
```

Also, Django uses `id` as the default Primary Key. You should have a VERY good reason to change that. So, better do

```
for i in range(5):
    ef = Fulfillment.objects.create(
        ...
        ...
    )
    por = OutReq.objects.create(
        out_req_uid=random.randint(500, 1000000000),
        fulfillment_uid=ef.id,
        ...
        ...
    )
```

Then `Fulfillment` will get automatically a new Primary Key called `id` (and aliased as `pk`), and you can use that as reference in the second object.

What's more, you can declare in the Model definition, that `OutReq.fullfilment` is a ForeignKey to `Fullfillment` and then simply assign the object, like so

```
for i in range(5):
    ef = Fulfillment.objects.create(
        ...
        ...
    )
    por = OutReq.objects.create(
        out_req_uid=random.randint(500, 1000000000),
        fulfillment=ef,
        ...
        ...
    )
```

And Django will automatically create a field `OutReq.fullfilment_id` and store the Primary Key to the `Fulfillment` instance there. Then you can access it like `por.fulfillment.id` etc.

[Dango Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)  make things a lot easier if you use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each Fulfillment has 5 requests.

```
# i assumed you want this is what you intented
for i in range(5):
    ef = Fulfillment.objects.create(
        fullfillment_uid=generateid(),
    )
    for j in range(5):
        por = OutReq.objects.create(
            out_req_uid=random.randint(500, 1000000000),
            fulfillment_uid=ef,
        )



# this is the bulk_create version of the above
fulfillment_list = []
fulfillment_ids = []
for i in range(5):
    ef_id = generateid()
    ef = Fulfillment(                   # note this doesn't create new instance of Fulfillment 
        fullfillment_uid=ef_id,
    )
    fulfillment_list.append(ef)
    fulfillment_ids.append(ef_id)

Fulfillment.objects.bulk_create(fulfillment_list)

req_list = []
for ef in Fulfillment.objects.filter(fullfillment_uid__in=fulfillment_ids):
    for j in range(5):
        por = OutReq(
            out_req_uid=random.randint(500, 1000000000),
            fulfillment_uid=ef,
        )
        req_list.append(por)
OutReq.objects.bulk_create(req_list)
```